# macOS Sierra console search criteria

Tags: macos, console

Is there a way to filter the console by multiple criteria?
I'd like to display only warnings and errors from the PHP log file. The following searches for the string `error warning` which doesn't exist

[image: error]

Comment: The Console app has limited functionality when analysing text log files;  it's built for filtering output from macOS's unified logging system.  You could try an alternative log analysis tool like lnav — http://lnav.org

Answer (score 1):

When you open Console, you automatically enter "All messages" section, but you can try switching to Errors and Faults filter which is already created there. [image]
It will give you additional search options the next time you try to filter messages, just click on a search bar and choose what type of messages you want to view.
Hope it'll help.

Comment: It appears this only works with the device log, which doesn't record the Apache/PHP errors. I moved my PHP log into the /Library/Logs folder that's listed in the Reports column. All Messages and Errors & Faults becomes grayed out.

Comment: I see. Sorry, there's no other solution I can think of at the moment.